# SQLite selecting very slow when recent inserts have been made

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqlcipher

I've got a table with about 7 million rows in it.  I'm inserting on average about one row every second into the database.  When I do this, I am noticing that it is taking an incredibly long time (as much as 15 seconds) to run a simple SELECT against the database, e.g. something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE rowid > 7100000
```

This select often returns no rows of data as sometimes no data has been inserted in this particular table.  It is often happening even when the table I'm writing to isn't even actually inserting rows into the table I am reading.

The idea is that there are two separate processes, one is adding data, the other is trying to get all new data that has not yet been read.  But the read side is connected to a UI and any noticable lag is intolerable, much less 15 seconds.  This is being run under Android and the the UI thread doesn't like being blocked for that long either and it is wreaking havoc.

My initial thought was maybe the insert is requiring an update to the indicies as originally I had the index on a different field (a time field).  This seems at least partially confirmed because if I use a database with only a few rows each select completes in a few milliseconds.  But when I re-created the table to only have the rowid as primary key it actually got slower.  I would expect inserting a new row at the end would always result in very fast reads when just comparing on the rowid as primary key.

I have tried enabling write ahead logging, but it appears that SQLCipher doesn't support this, at least not directly, as it doesn't adhere to the lastest API for android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.  Even using "PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL" in the postKey hook hasn't made any difference.

What's going on here?  How can I speed up my selects?

Update: I tried getting rid of sqlcipher and just using plain sqlite to see if that was a factor.  I used sqlcipher_export to export to a plaintext database, and then used the default `android.database.sqlite.SQLCipher`.  The delay time dropped from 10-20s to 1.8-2.8s.  I then removed write-ahead and it dropped further to 1.3-2.7s.  So the issue is still noticably there, although it did get a lot better.

Comment: I would begin by identifying the impact of the concurrent inserts on the application vs the querying. In other words, disable the inserting of new data, and measure how long the same select statement takes to run. Also, it would be helpful to know how many rows are inserted at a time, and whether that operation is running in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is ultimately file-based, and there is no portable mechanism to communicate to another process which part of a file has changed. So when one process has written something, all other processes must drop their caches when they access the database file the next time.

If possible, modify your architecture that both parts of the code are in the same process and share the same database connection. (With multiple threads, this requires locking, but SQLite has not much concurrency anyway.)

Alternatively, write the new data into a separate database, and let the UI app move it to its own database.

I don't know why SQLCipher is so much slower (it's unlikely to be the CPU overhead of the decryption).